# AngularJS Scope Doesn't Update After New Request

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm fairly new to angularJS still but have been reading a lot of material and finally started to test out the things that I was learning. I'm currently trying to write code that uses a service which reaches the last.FM API and returns a list of similar artists. I'm returning the result fine from the API and can see results if I send them to the console. That said, after I do one search all subsequent searches don't update the scope properly. My code is as follows:

**Controller**

```
.controller('lastFMController', function($scope, lastFM) {
    $scope.search = function(artist) {
        lastFM.getSimilar(artist).then(function(result) {
            $scope.artists = result.similarartists.artist;
        }, function(error) {
            $scope.error = error;
        });
    };
});
```

**View**

```
<form role="form">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="artist">search for a music artist and see similiar artists</label>
    <input type="text" name="artist" class="form-control" ng-model="artist" placeholder="type an artist's name">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="search(artist)">search</button>
</form>

<hr ng-if="artists" />

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 fade in" ng-repeat="artist in artists">
        <h3>{{ artist.name }}</h3>
        <p><a target="_blank" href="http://{{ artist.url }}" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">view on last.fm</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Service**

```
.factory('lastFM', function($q, $http) {
    var deferred = $q.defer(),
        self = this,
        apiKey = "KEY";

    return {
        getSimilar: function(artist) {
            this.url = 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getsimilar&artist=' + artist + '&api_key=' + apiKey + '&format=json&autocorrect=1';
            this.error = false;

            $http.get(this.url).success(function(data) {
                if (data.error) {
                    deferred.reject(data.error.message);
                }
                else if (!angular.isUndefined(data.similarartists) && angular.isObject(data.similarartists.artist)) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
                }
                else {
                    deferred.reject('Something went wrong');
                }
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
});
```

As I said, when I do my initial search I get a result that displays, but all subsequent searches don't update the scope. I tried $scope.$apply but it said that it was already running that command. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your factory, you define a deferred. This deferred is resolved on the first call to getSimilar, not on each call (because factories are singletons). Furthermore, you don't need the deferred because $http returns a promise itself. So remove the deferred initialization in your factory, and return the $http call in getSimilar. If you really need the extra deferred, initalize it inside getSimilar.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I didn't realize that resolving the factory once would leave it permanently resolved. All works now.